# How to integrate getstream in laravel

Tags: laravel, getstream-io

please i am trying to setup getstream in laravel. Their tutorial has not been very helpful to me personally, I think it is quite old. How do I setup the models, for now i just want the user to see posts that he and his friends make, as simple as that. Please help me. Thanks

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Follow;
use Auth;
use App;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class FollowController extends Controller {

/**
 * Let current user follow user $target_id
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $target_id = $request->target;
    $user_id = Auth::id();
    $params = array(
        'user_id' => Auth::id(),
        'target_id' => $target_id,
    );
    $follow = Follow::withTrashed($params)->where($params)->first();

    if ($follow === null) {
        $follow = new Follow($params);
        $follow->save();
        FeedManager::followUser($follow->user_id, $follow->target_id);
    } elseif ($follow->trashed()){
        $follow->restore();
        FeedManager::followUser($follow->user_id, $follow->target_id);
    }
    return Redirect::to(Input::get('next'));
}

public function destroy($resource)
{
    $follow = Follow::firstOrNew(array(
            'id' => $resource,
            'user_id' => Auth::id()
        )
    );
    if ($follow->id !== null) {
        $manager = App::make('feed_manager');
        FeedManager::unfollowUser($follow->user_id, $follow->target_id);
        $follow->delete();
    }
    return Redirect::to(Input::get('next'));
}
```

}

Comment: can you add some more detail about your problem? your use case is covered in the Laravel example app

Comment: Going through the app I noticed that the environment is a bit different, am using laravel 5.1, this is really giving me a hard time. Also I get this Class 'App\Http\Controllers\FeedManager' not found. What's is a pin and what's an item.

Comment: where is the code that tries to include "App\Http\Controllers\FeedManager"?   please add more context so that is possible for someone to come up with a solution for this ;)

Comment: The code above is for the FollowController. I think the issues am having is simply because I am trying to replicate the example into mine and  I think it would cause errors because am trying to achieve something different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are missing some of the setup steps outlined here: https://github.com/GetStream/Stream-Laravel (the Stream-Laravel package)

Specifically to your error message, it seems like your app does not have the FeedManager facade configured.

Comment: @ifeoluwaking were you able to find a solution for this problem? if my answer was correct please mark it as such ;)